# Advice on converting JS into AMP code format for Shopify

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, amp-html, shopify-app

The plugin that I'm using is [Shopsheriff](https://apps.shopify.com/amp-google)

I have tried the following:

```
<!-- AMP iframe --><script async custom-element="amp-iframe" src="https://onetapsignup.com/otg/shopify-script.js?shop=khuba-llc.myshopify.com/v0/amp-iframe-0.1.js"></script>
```

This is the error I receive:

[image: Error Message]

Any suggestions would be helpful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you loaded the AMP iframe lib?

Comment: @JayGray - I'm new to coding so I'm unsure what that is. Most likely not... the way you see in the example is the exact what I have it set up. If you would be so kind to walk me through it I would be extremely grateful!